# cuda v6.5 nvcc with VS 2013 failed, mysterious msg

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cuda, nvcc

Just upgraded to CUDA v6.5 and installed Visual Studio 2013 Community under Win 7. Some codes used to compile in CUDA 6.0 and VS 2008 now failed with this mysterious message,

> "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

It's not even a compiler error message. So wondering what's wrong?

The compile command is

`nvcc -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 tt-log-limit.cu -lcublas -lcurand -o lgl`

My config is a bit different from the usual, where I installed both `CUDA` and `VS 2013 Community` on F drive, as could be seen in my `PATH`,

`PATH=F:\Programs\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin;F:\Programs\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\libnvvp;;C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin;F:\Programs\Haskell\2014.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin;F:\Programs\Haskell\2014.2.0.0\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011b\bin;F:\Chome;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;F:\Programs\Haskell\2014.2.0.0\mingw\bin;C:\libgsl-1.8\lib;C:\libgsl-1.8\include;C:\libgsl-1.8\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;F:\Programs\nodejs\;F:\Programs\MSVS13\VC\bin\amd64;F:\Programs\MSVS13\VC\bin;C:\MikTex\miktex\bin\;C:\Users\rspace\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\rspace\AppData\Roaming\npm`

The version of nvcc and cl are shown below :

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jul_25_06:28:08_CDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, V6.5.13

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Comment: From the description it is not clear what application emits this error at what time, so this may not have anything to do with CUDA at all. This error message typically means that there are superfluous spaces or dis-allowed characters in a path specification. It *maybe* due to the superfluous second semicolon here: `F:\Programs\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\libnvvp;;`

Comment: Just checked, the double ;; is not the culprit.

Comment: There is too little information given in the question to diagnose what may be going on, and it is not even clear that this is CUDA related at all ("not even a compiler error message"). In the absence of an MCVE that can reproduce the behavior, I will vote to close.

Comment: I don't get why this question has -3. I have the exact problem (with Cuda v9.1 and MSVS2017(15.4), and would describe it the same. Compilation works under VS, but when running (the correct vcvars) command-line, I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." without any explanation.

Comment: @JHBonarius Stackoverflow is full of soup-nazis. I ran into this kind of downvote all the time. Pls upvote if you disagree.

Comment: I did. So before it was even -4

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix, after a couple rounds of uninstalls and reboots. As it's been observed elsewhere, CUDA has some paths hard coded, so the location of Visual Studio is important.

I removed both CUDA v6.5 and VS 2013 completely, and reinstalled them again. This time I let them take their default locations on C drive. So, CUDA is installed in

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5

and VS is in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0

That solved the problem. My .cu codes compile without a glitch.

Comment: So for CUDA v9.1.85 and MSVS2017/15.4.5, which seem to work together under the IDE, this fix does not work. At least: I have them installed in their default directories.

Comment: @JHBonarius what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with cuda 9.1 in windows 10.

When I opened rapid environment editor I saw that the cuda path for 9.1 was marked in red as being invalid. (Although when I copy pasted the path in question, it opened to the correct folder).

I eventually copy-pasted from the (valid) path for cuda 9.0, changed the 0 to a 1. It worked. Maybe Cuda created the path with an illegal whitespace character or something.